# VBA, Pivot formula to include last 52 weeks of data

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a pivot that gets data from up to 2 years. I select all columns like `Sheet!$A:$F`.

How can I alter the formula to only include the previous 52 weeks from today?

Sample Data:

```
+-------------+
| 1-Jan-2019  |
| 2-Jan-2019  |
| 3-Jan-2019  |
| 4-Jan-2019  |
| 7-Jan-2019  |
| 8-Jan-2019  |
| 9-Jan-2019  |
| 10-Jan-2019 |
| 11-Jan-2019 |
| 14-Jan-2019 |
| 15-Jan-2019 |
| 16-Jan-2019 |
| 17-Jan-2019 |
| 18-Jan-2019 |
| 21-Jan-2019 |
| 22-Jan-2019 |
| 23-Jan-2019 |
| 24-Jan-2019 |
| 25-Jan-2019 |
| 28-Jan-2019 |
| 29-Jan-2019 |
| 30-Jan-2019 |
| 31-Jan-2019 |
| 1-Feb-2019  |
| 4-Feb-2019  |
| 5-Feb-2019  |
| 6-Feb-2019  |
| 7-Feb-2019  |
| 8-Feb-2019  |
| 11-Feb-2019 |
| 12-Feb-2019 |
| 13-Feb-2019 |
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a date filter to your `PivotField`.

With the `DateSerial` function you can subtract from today, e. g. 1 year (or 52 * 7 days or whatever).

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WSname").PivotTables("PTname").PivotFields("PFname")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .PivotFilters.Add2 _
        Type:=xlDateBetween, _
        Value1:=CStr(DateSerial(Year(Date) - 1, Month(Date), Day(Date))), _
        Value2:=CStr(Date), _
        WholeDayFilter:=True
End With
```